# ClassCastException b/w IBMorb and jacorb jars in WAS 8.5.5

Tags: java, corba, websphere-8, jacorb

I have an application which is using jacorb.jar (org.omg.orb.ORB.class). When i deploying my war file in WAS 8.5.5, I am getting classcast exceptions with ibmorb located at openJdk/jre/lib/ibmorb.jar file. Could anyone help me in using jacorb.jar and resolving errors.

**Error:**

```
[3/3/15 5:30:51:863 PST] 00000001 ActivityServi E   WACT0001E: The method pre_init(ORBInitInfo) in class com.ibm.ws.activity.remote.cos.ActivityServiceClientInterceptor received an unexpected exception; 
the exception stack trace follows: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jacorb.orb.portableInterceptor.ORBInitInfoImpl incompatible with com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ExtendedORBInitInfo
at com.ibm.ws.activity.remote.cos.ActivityServiceClientInterceptor.pre_init(ActivityServiceClientInterceptor.java:219)
at org.jacorb.orb.ORB.interceptorPreInit(Unknown Source)
at org.jacorb.orb.ORB.internalInit(Unknown Source)
at org.jacorb.orb.ORB.set_parameters(Unknown Source)
at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:371)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jacorb.orb.ORB incompatible with com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB
at com.ibm.ws.orb.GlobalORBFactory.init(GlobalORBFactory.java:92)
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORBImpl.initializeORB(EJSORBImpl.java:179)
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSClientORBImpl.<init>(EJSClientORBImpl.java:83)
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSClientORBImpl.<init>(EJSClientORBImpl.java:59)
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORB.init(EJSORB.java:102)
```

Comment: Where have you placed jacorb.jar?  WebSphere Application Server doesn't support overriding the ORB that it provides.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I have kept jacorb.jar file in JVM classpath through admin console. In my application it is mandatory to use jacorb.jar and current task is to migrate to websphere from jboss. Completely locked at this stage as all my trails to overrride ORB of websphere is failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM doesn't support third party ORB as it provides its own ORB. You can find the orb.properties with default properties in IBM JAVA jre folder. If you want to add anything related to ORB that need to inform JRE , we can add an entry in this property folder.

I have completely removed the JacORB from my code and used IBM ORB. They wont be any problem if you compile your code with JacORB and to use the same in IBM websphere as the package structure and method signature wont change. I have tested this practically.

Refer to this thread for more information in creating a corba name space and using it in code. If you follow those, you wont need to add jacorb jars in IBM websphere.

[Corba NameService configuration in Websphere 8.5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28939289/corba-nameservice-configuration-in-websphere-8-5-5)