# WAS8.5.5 not incorporating Jacorb application

Tags: java, websphere, corba, orb, jacorb

I had an application which is tightly coupled with jacorb and it is working great with Jboss. Now, i have to migrate this application to deploy the same in Websphere 8.5.5. General flow is , my application will reach another system (developed in C++) through corba usign jacorb. **since IBM is having its own ORB implementations, My application is getting deployed in websphere. If my application is modified to make use of IBM orb jars, then 80% of applciation have to change.** Kindly suggest me the way to include jacord proeprties and jar to resolve the errors.

My trails : All trails are independent to each other.

1)   Kept my orb.properties, jacorb.jar and removed IBM orb.properties in WAS->JAVA->JRE->lib
2) Included my files in JVM classpath through Admin console.(Server failed to start after this change).

3) Modified the IBM orb.properties with jacorb properties but getting classcast exceptions.

Errors:

```
[3/4/15 0:52:23:175 PST] 00000001 ContainerHelp E   WSVR0501E: Error creating component null [class com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ORBImpl]java.lang.NullPointerException

at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:877)
at org.jacorb.config.JacORBConfiguration.setAttribute(Unknown Source)
at org.jacorb.config.JacORBConfiguration.setAttributes(Unknown Source)
at org.jacorb.config.JacORBConfiguration.init(Unknown Source)
at org.jacorb.config.JacORBConfiguration.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.jacorb.config.JacORBConfiguration.getConfiguration(Unknown Source)
at org.jacorb.orb.ORB.set_parameters(Unknown Source)
at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:371)
at com.ibm.ws.orb.GlobalORBFactory.init(GlobalORBFactory.java:92)



[3/4/15 0:52:23:347 PST] 00000001 ContainerHelp E   WSVR0501E: Error creating component com.ibm.ws.naming.bootstrap.NameServerImpl@e69374e2[_serverProcessType=UnManagedProcess, _listener=null, 

Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to initialize the ORB [Root exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.getOrb(Helpers.java:400)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.<init>(UrlContextImpl.java:177)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlns.genericURLContext.<init>(genericURLContext.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlns.genericURLContextRoot.<init>(genericURLContextRoot.java:79)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlns.genericURLContextFactory.createURLContextRoot(genericURLContextFactory.java:110)
... 51 more

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.getOrb(Helpers.java:391)
... 55 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jacorb.orb.ORB incompatible with com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB
at com.ibm.ws.orb.GlobalORBFactory.init(GlobalORBFactory.java:92)
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORBImpl.initializeORB(EJSORBImpl.java:179)
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSClientORBImpl.<init>(EJSClientORBImpl.java:83)
at
```

Thanks for your support in advance.

Comment: Using third party ORB in WAS is not supported - check this threads https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=2e1c98f5-6120-45cc-a5fa-94cb751f3a23&ps=50 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28833588/classcastexception-b-w-ibmorb-and-jacorb-jars-in-was-8-5-5?rq=1. Why do you need to change 80% of the app? Are you using some no standard features? Did you try to use IBM ORB?

Comment: thanks Gas for your response. My application is very tightly coupled with Jacorb. During the build process, this is the first jar lets say ABC.jar we used to build and based on this only entire application build process depends . I didnt tried to  change to use IBM ORB as it is very much complicated.  I had a query like, Is jacorb or IBM ORB part comes into picture only at runtime ???

Comment: How is your application tightly coupled to JacORB? JacORB tries to be standards compliant (although there are a number of QoS options available).

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your response. My application is contacting other application developed in c++. For this connection, i am using jacorb jar to build the required files from .idl files. If i use IBM ORB, it will generate file using IBM orb and C++ application also required to be recompiled , correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: The IDL stubs should be portable i.e. should not need recompiling.  
  
Note that JacORB can generate stubs in different compatibility levels - it would be helpful to know your version of JacORB and the IDL generation command you have used.

Comment: Hi Nike, Sorry the delay.. I am using Jacorb 2.2.2 version and the commands i am using to convert idl to java is mentioned below.          set                          IDLCLASSPATH=%EXT_DIR%\JacORB\JacORB_2.2.2\lib\jacorb.jar;%EXT_DIR%\JacORB\JacORB_2.2.2\lib\idl.jar;%EXT_DIR%\JacORB\JacORB_2.2.2\lib\logkit-1.2.jar;%CLASSPATH%

set **IDL2JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -classpath %IDLCLASSPATH% org.jacorb.idl.parser -noskel**

Comment: Hi, I have just executed my IDL files using Sun idlj command and i have got required files. Which means that, I can generate code using either idlj or jacorb libraries. Now, my main concern is to deploy these files in IBM websphere. As WAS is providing its own ORB implementation, how can i incorporate third party ORB in websphere. Few threads states, IBM doesnt support any third party ORB frameworks. As my application will sell to different customers and they will deploy in different servers, i can't use server specific ORB jars to generate the code.Suggest me the best way to over this problem

Comment: If your application isn't using any proprietary ORB features then you could use any ORB ; even the WAS one? The stubs, whether they are generated by Oracle or by JacORB (p.s. current version is 3.6) should be portable and therefore you could generate with one ORB IDL compiler and run with another ORB.

Comment: Thanks Nick, you are correct .. IDL are portable. I have used the same jars created using Jacorb in Websphere and it worked.