# Corba NameService configuration in Websphere 8.5.5

Tags: java, websphere, corba

As part of my application requirement, I have to configure a attribute called `"ORBInitRef.NameService=corbaloc:iiop:ABCDE012:14888/NameService"` in Websphere 8.5.5. Earlier i have used Jboss for my applciation deployment but now have to use WAS. In, WAS where should i have to configure this attribute in admin console? Is there any way to do it through orb.properties file in WAS root folder. Please let me know to approach??

Comment: What you want to do exactly? Please describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below steps to configurable Corba Name service in WAS 8.5.5 in admin console.

--> Environment --> Name Space Bindings --> New --> Provide your corba details here.

**Example:**

1) corba URL : corbaloc:iiop:ABCDE012:14888/NameService

2) provide Lookup name. using this, u will get a RootContext by lookup like JNDI.

**Code Example :**

InitialContext context = new InitialContext();

org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContext rootContext=(NamingContext)context.lookup("testing");

using the rootContext, you can fetch the server stubs and preform the operation required.